# How can I resolve the "LOCALDB_ERROR_AUTO_INSTANCE_CREATE_FAILED" error after installing SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, localdb, sql-server-2014-express

I have been using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1. All working fine.

Recently I installed SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB. After installing, I am not able to work with `LocalDB`. I get odd errors, one I get is `LOCALDB_ERROR_AUTO_INSTANCE_CREATE_FAILED`

And according to [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270331.aspx) I should find information in the event log, but there is nothing at all in the event log.

When `sqllocaldb` command works and I can check the `LocalDB` installed as this:

```
C:\> sqllocaldb v
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)
```

but whenever I try to work with my projects I get connection related errors. The underlying error mentions that automatic instance creation didn't work.

**UPDATE**: this is resolved by changing connection strings from `(LocalDB)\v11.0` to `(LocalDB)\v12.0`

Answer (score 0):

May be it's:

> (localdb)\projectsv12

I have also encountered similar problem. Try it :D

Answer (score 0):

use for SQLExpress 2014 (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

see also http://www.michael-whelan.net/sql-server-localdb-2014-connection-string/